# Remove "type" attribute from script tags in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on WordPress Site,these warnings are coming on every single page, Is there any method to resolve this.

> Warning:The type attribute is unnecessary for JavaScript resources. `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: I didn't found any solution to resolve these warning.

Comment: See this link https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/287830/remove-type-attribute-from-script-and-style-tags-added-by-wordpress

Answer (score 4):

As of WordPress 5.3 you can add 'style' and 'script' to add_theme_support for Html5 to remove the type attributes.

```
function register_html_support() {

    add_theme_support( 'html5', array( 'script', 'style' ) );

}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_html_support' );
```

Answer (score 3):

Add following code to your theme's functions.php

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'prefix_remove_template_redirect', 10, 2);

function prefix_remove_template_redirect(){
  ob_start( function( $buffer ){
    $buffer = str_replace( array( 
        '<script type="text/javascript">',
        "<script type='text/javascript'>", 
        "<script type='text/javascript' src=",
        '<script type="text/javascript" src=',
        '<style type="text/css">', 
        "' type='text/css' media=", 
        '<style type="text/css" media',
        "' type='text/css'>"
    ), 
    array(
        '<script>', 
        "<script>", 
        "<script src=",
        '<script src=',
        '<style>', 
        "' media=", 
        '<style media',
        "' >"
    ), $buffer );

    return $buffer;
  });
};
```

This will change `<script type="text/javascript">` to `<script>` And will change `<style type="text/css">` to `<style>`. It can be done by `script_loader_tag` but its given theme check validation error.

Update:
From WordPress 5.3, You can use following.

```
function theme_name_setup() {

    add_theme_support( 'html5', array( 'script', 'style' ) );

}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_name_setup' );
```

Comment: This broke my post: displays a blank screen.

Comment: It should work. I used that code in my projects. and it's working.

Comment: @SherylHohman remove numbers `8798` from function's name. it works for me.
thanks @JahirulIslamMamun

Comment: Works good and with plugins on custom built themes. Easy to understand and modify for your needs. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Add the below code to your theme's functions.php

```
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'clean_script_tag');
  function clean_script_tag($input) {
  $input = str_replace("type='text/javascript' ", '', $input);
  return str_replace("'", '"', $input);
}
```

This will change `<script type="text/javascript">` to `<script>` for the plugin loaded scripts.

And then change `<script type="text/javascript">` to `<script>` in your theme's header an  footer php files.

Comment: I used this , but still it shows type attribute with script tag

Comment: I am not able to find why this code is not running on my project

Comment: How you doing ? What themes you are using? What is your WordPress Version?

Comment: Looks like you need to manually search in your plugins as wel as in your theme

Comment: I am creating my own theme, working on latest version of WordPress 4.9.6

Comment: Can you share the site url ?

Comment: I can't share my url, but I will create dummy url for testing purpose, I will update you soon. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i added two things. This works for me:

```
#one for JS mime-type
add_action( 'template_redirect', function(){
  ob_start( function( $buffer ){
       $buffer = str_replace( array( 'type="text/javascript"', "type='text/javascript'" ), '', $buffer );        
       return $buffer;
    });
});
#one for CSS-Mime-Type
add_action( 'template_redirect', function(){
    ob_start( function( $buffer ){
        $buffer = str_replace( array( 'type="text/css"', "type='text/css'" ), '', $buffer );        
        return $buffer;
    });
});
```

I know you can do both in one function, but here can you decide for oneself what you want (JS or CSS or both)